# method fetchDataByName(String) is undefined for type new FilterQueryProvider

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I have the following method, which fetches data from a database

```
public Cursor fetchDataByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {
       Log.w(TAG, inputText);
       Cursor mCursor = null;
       if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
            mCursor = db.query(
            .......
            return mCursor;
       }
```

I would like to display the result in a ListView with a custom adapter 
but I have an error in the code.

```
dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
       public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
              return this.fetchDataByName(constraint.toString()); //error here
       }
```

error message:

> the method `fetchDataByName(String)` is undefined for type `new FilterQueryProvider`

The error seems pretty self-explanatory, but I can't figure out how to fix it. How can I update my code to get my desired behaviour?

Comment: have u try it after removing `this` ? or by using class context in which u have created `fetchDataByName` method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside an anonymous class using `this` wont help since it refers to the current object, so you can try without using `this`

or

```
return OuterClassName.this.fetchDataByName(constraint.toString());
```

Now since the `fetchDataByName(String)` method throws `SQLException` then you will have to include a `try catch` block as follows

```
public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
    try{
        return fetchDataByName(constraint.toString());
    }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: the method `fetchDataByName()` and the call to `setFilterQueryProvider()` both in the same class, and when i use `this` or `OuterClassName.this.fetchDataByName(constraint.toString());` give error `unhandled exception type SQlException`, but also with the try/catch i should give add a `return statement`

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `fetchDataByName()` in some database class, but try to call this method as a member of `FilterQueryProvider`. If you want to access it from `runQuery()`, you must have an instance of your database class

```
class DatabaseAdapter {
    public Cursor fetchDataByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {
    ...
    }
}

DatabaseAdapter adapter = ...;

dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
                  public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                      return adapter.fetchDataByName(constraint.toString());
                  }
```

If both the method `fetchDataByName()` and the call to `setFilterQueryProvider()` are in the same class, you can just omit `this.`

```
dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
                  public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                      return fetchDataByName(constraint.toString());
                  }
```

Comment: the method `fetchDataByName()` and  `setFilterQueryProvider()` both in the same class, and when i do as you said, give error `unhandled exception type SQlException`, but also with the try/catch i should give `add  return statement`

Comment: @user2206914 Then you must first debug `fetchDataByName`. When you add a try/catch, you must return some value in every possible branch, of course.